# kotlin var property in tornadofx ViewModel and ItemViewModel

Tags: tornadofx

As per docs, kotlin var properties can be bind in ViewModel as

```
    // Kotlin var property
class PersonVarViewModel(person: Person) : ViewModel() {
    val name = bind { person.observable(Person::name) }
}
```

It seems like doesn't work. 
How to solve this issue. IDE shows red underline bellow "bind"
but if i write

```
   val name = bind(RoomType::name)
```

it shows no error. but updating the value using UI fields does'nt update the model value. 
Please help

Comment: your property probably needs to be a `var`, not a `val`, and I think you need to make `person` a member of the class with `var` or `val`

Comment: actually, `name` can be `val`, the problem is with your class declaration, see my answer

Comment: post the actual error you are seeing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the ItemViewModel aware of the person instance, but also let it react to changes to the underlying item later. You need to assign the person you pass in to the `item` property of the ItemViewModel. This can be done by passing it in the constructor:

```
class PersonVarViewModel(person: Person) : ItemViewModel<Person>(person) {
    val name = bind(Person::name)
}
```

Be aware that if you add this constructor, you can only use the that viewmodel with injection if you push it manually into scopes, since it can't be instantiated by the framework. You should therefore either add a noargs constructor as well, or simply omit the person parameter and assign to item after you create it.

If you update the value in the underlying person, it will only be visible in the view model if the value is observable. If not, you have to call `rollback()` to update changes from the person. You can call rollback for specific fields only.

If possible, use observable properties in your domain model objects to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 1):

In your class declaration, use `var person: Person`.

`person` needs to be a member of the class, not just a parameter to the constructor.  You can do this by declaring it `var` or `val` in the constructor parameters, or you can add a member field to the class the conventional way and assign it (probably using `by property`, but not sure if that's what you want)

```
class PersonVarViewModel(var person: Person) : ViewModel() {
    val name = bind { person.observable(Person::name) }
}
```

For `ItemViewModel` ...

```
class PersonVarViewModel(var person: Person) : ItemViewModel<Person>() {
    val name = bind { person.observable(Person::name) }
}
```

Comment: what about ItemViewModel()?

Comment: do you mean the compiler is complaining? or something else

Comment: Thank you! this ended a long search, the trick was to bind the observable to the base variable and not the property